# All elements (like images) in a heavy page to load together in the browser

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net, ajax

I have a heavy asp.net page. While it renders, some images come in the beginning then progressively it loads the rest. We want to  get rid of the behavior. The page should display only after all the content is ready and it should display together.  How do we achieve it? Is there any way we can ask the page to wait until it is completely ready?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could have an element fill the page, and when the javascript event onLoad fires hide it.

```
<div id='loading' style='z-index:100; width:100%; height:100%; background:#FF0000'>Loading, please wait!</div>

<script type='text/javascript'>

window.onload = function()
{
    document.getElementById('loading').style.display = 'none';
}

</script>
```

Comment: Upvote because it's a useful answer in that it directly answers Lijo's question. But I still think it's usually a bad practice.

Answer (score 5):

It can be done, but I recommend against it. Using JavaScript (see @TJHeuvel response), you can wait until the DOM is ready before you "flip on the lights," (usually changing a hidden container to a visible one) but ask yourself if it's a good user experience:

1. The current way: as the page loads, your user can theoretically start getting information and understanding how the page is laid out.
2. The proposed way: if the page is as heavy as you say, the user goes to the URL and sees what... a "loading" animated GIF for 5 seconds (or more)? I can only speak for myself, but I'd rather see SOME content than none, even if it's not fully rendered.

Answer (score 2):

See the concept **Image Sprite** in css. You can solve this problem using this method.Make only one image by combining all the images on the page.And then use image sprite. Many websites uses this so that content on the page loads at a single time.

Refer this http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp

Comment: Also useful. Hard to be effective with just one sprite for all images, but certainly related images (all nav items, buttons, and widgets, for example) can be put into a sprite to reduce the # of HTTP requests and fill in the images in larger chunks at a time.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding image problem, As Rohal say Image Sprite in css are the best but if you can't use it then try using smaller size image that are re-sized properly please also check out this [Hanselman blog](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NuGetPackageOfWeek11ImageResizerEnablesCleanClearImageResizingInASPNET.aspx) where he tell about imageresizer utility its really nice one.... hope this helps